# Error in reading and writing files in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert files from one format to other in Python. The current format is DAQ (data acquisition format), which is read in first. Then I use `undaq Tools` module to write the files to hdf5 format.

```
import glob
ctnames = glob.glob('*.daq')
```

Following are the few filenames (there are 100 in total):

```
ctnames
['Cars_20160601_01.daq',
 'Cars_20160601_02.daq',
 'Cars_20160601_03.daq',
 'Cars_20160601_04.daq',
 'Cars_20160601_05.daq',
 'Cars_20160601_06.daq',
 'Cars_20160601_07.daq',
.
.
.
## Importing undaq tools:
from undaqTools import Daq
```

### Reading the DAQ files and writing to hdf5:

```
for n in ctnames:     
   x = daq.read(n)
   daq.write_hd5(x)
```

Following is the error I got:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\undaqtools-0.2.3-py2.7.egg\undaqTools\daq.py:405: RuntimeWarning: Failed loading file on frame 46970. (stopped reading file)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6fe7a8c9496d> in <module>()
      1 for n in ctnames:
----> 2    x = daq.read(n)
      3    daq.write_hd5(x)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\undaqtools-0.2.3-py2.7.egg\undaqTools\daq.pyc in read_daq(self, filename, elemlist, loaddata, process_dynobjs, interpolate_missing_frames)
    272 
    273         if loaddata:
--> 274             self._loaddata()
    275             self._unwrap_lane_deviation()
    276 

C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\undaqtools-0.2.3-py2.7.egg\undaqTools\daq.pyc in _loaddata(self)
    449                         assert tmpdata[name].shape[0] == frame.frame.shape[0]
    450                     else:
--> 451                         assert tmpdata[name].shape[1] == frame.frame.shape[0]
    452 
    453         # cast as Element objects

AssertionError:
```

## Questions

I have 2 questions:
1. How do I know which of the 100 files is throwing the error?
2. How do I skip the files if they throw the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `read()` call in a try/except block.  If you get an exception, print the current filename and skip to the next one.

```
for n in ctnames:     
    try:
        x = daq.read(n)
    except AssertionError:
        print 'Could not process file %s.  Skipping.' % n
        continue
    daq.write_hd5(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the try/except block but it has skipped all the files. I know for sure that not all files throw error if `daq.read()` is used individually for each. Is my loop structure correct? My goal is to convert each file from daq to hdf5, e.g. 'Cars_20160601_01.daq' to 'Cars_20160601_01.hdf5' and so on.

Comment: When you say _it has skipped all the files_, do you mean that it prints the "could not process file" message for all 100 files?  If so, then all 100 files are actually getting the exception.

Comment: Perhaps when an exception occurs, something inside `daq` becomes corrupted, causing all subsequent reads to fail?  Do you need to create a fresh `daq` object for each loop iteration?

Comment: Another test would be to hardcode the `ctnames` list, including just a few files (or only one), and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thank you! Putting `daq = Daq()` inside the loop solved the problem.